# How to create a consolidate system data matrix for least frequency

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a multiple system data with same start and end date and time. However frequency of system data is not same.

I want to create a consolidated matrix of all systems on the basis of least frequency.

Please see below example for more detail:

System 1 data frequency is 1 hour and System 2 data frequency is 1 minute. I want to create a matrix on the basis of least frequency for all systems. Please find an image attached herewith.

Please let me know if you have any related queries or need any other information.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can anyone please provide the solution how to proceed further for above requirement?